# The MySQL service could not be started

Tags: mysql, service, cmd

MySQL Service don't start automatically on system bootup, and when I try to start MySQL service it shows the following output

```
C:\Windows\system32>net start MySQL
The MySQL service is starting.
The MySQL service could not be started.

The service did not report an error.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.
```

Please suggest some way to solve the problem, if you ever came across such a problem.

Comment: Look at the permissions on log files and make sure they are correct.

Comment: I had the same error right now, when I tried to install multiple instances of mysql. In my case, I forgotten to change right path to data folder in my.ini (my2.ini In my case). So take also a look (a little bit late :) ) into your my.ini file

Answer (score 6):

My MySQL80 server failed to start because my.ini was saved with UTF-8 encoding instead of ANSI.

1. Find my.ini by typing echo %PROGRAMDATA% at a command prompt and look for the MySQL directory.
2. Open my.ini in Notepad and use File -> Save As...
3. In the Encoding select list by the Save button, choose ANSI and save.

Comment: You saved my hours! I was having the same problem. weirdo!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to resolve the error where the service does not start is by going into the registry as Administrator.

Navigate to HKLM\System\ControlSet001\Services\MySQL Change image path to "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe" --defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MyNewSQL\bin\MyNewSQL.ini MyNewSQL

My problem (same as yours):

Current Registry Setting: C:\MySQLs\MySQLDev\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=C:/MySQLs/MySQLDev/MySQLDev.ini MySQLDev

Change Registry Setting to: C:\MySQLs\MySQLDev\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=C:/MySQLs/MySQLDev/MySQLDev.ini MySQLDev

Rerun "net start MySQLDev"

The MySQLDev service is starting. The MySQLDev service was started successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the Host Network Service on Windows solved the problem.

You can do this with an admin Powershell/ Command Prompt session by running:

```
net stop hns
net start hns
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, it does not seem to put any error information in EventViewer. To find error info, in your `my.ini` file, look for a line like this:

```ini
# Error Logging.
log-error="SERVERNAME.err"
```

look for that .err file in your installation directory (`dir /s *.err`) and it should have information about what is going wrong.

Except that, it seems when starting the server (ie: `net start mysql`), it still does not log there, so lookup your service and try the command manually at the command line.

It should be something like this:

```bash
<install_path>\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="<path_to_my_ini>" <instance_name>
```

Try that same command manually, except for some reason remove the `<instance_name>` part. You should then get both error output from `mysqld.exe` and something written to `SERVERNAME.err`.

For me the problem was: I had stupidly removed an empty Uploads folder and redundant `my.ini` from the data path. It wanted that Uploads folder to exist. Once the Uploads folder was remade, and the `my.ini` copied back, the service started.